# HTML/CSS ul list of links won't align horizontally

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am trying to make a horizontal navigation bar at the top of my page. When I added the links to my unordered list, they were no longer formatted to be horizontal and are vertical down the center of the page.

I read that I need to format my margins to auto, but I think they are already formatted correctly.

```css
html,
head {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Goudy Old Style', Garamond, 'Big Caslon', Sans-Serif;
}
.header {
  background: url(https://imagesus-ssl.homeaway.com/mda01/2358e4a3-3618-473b-b198-457b887edb98.1.10) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 30em;
}
.nav {
  background: rgba(24, 24, 24, .6);
  height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: initial;
  list-style-image: initial;
  padding: 0.75em 1em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #333333;
  height: 1.5em;
}
.title {
  font-family: 'calibri', cursive;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 3em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-right: 8em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}
.supporting {
  background: #FFF9E9;
  height: 30em;
  padding: 3em;
  color: #56482D;
}
.quote {
  height: 5em 2em;
  width: 8em;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  float: left;
  font-family: cursive;
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 2em;
}
.description {
  display: block;
  float: auto;
}
.description p:nth-child(9) {
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 10x;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="btn" href="https://www.poipukapili22.com"> Home</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Reviews</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="https://www.google.com"> Photos & Videos</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Maps/Location</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Amenities</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Information</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Rates</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Check Availability</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Book Your Stay</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Contact Us</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    Poipu Kapili #22
  </div>
</div>
<div class="supporting">
  <div class="quote">
    <p>"From the lanai we watched snorkel boats and whale spouts right out front."
    </p>
    <p>Georgina Marion <span> Guest, Jan 2016</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <h1> Spectacular views and deluxe furnishings will make Poipu Kapili #22 your home away from home.</h1> 
    <p>This spacious and comfortable home has an air conditioned master suite and two full bathrooms.</p>
    <p>Enjoy the ocean views from living room, dining room, kitchen and lanai. Drift to sleep in the luxury of a king bed.</p>
    <p>The views will provide you with endless hours of seasonal whale watching and ocean views. Poipu Kapili is one of the finest resorts on Kauai. With only 60 units on five beautifully-landscaped acres Poipu Kapili offers maximum privacy. Relax and enjoy
      the view from the pool and BBQ area as well. Keep in shape and play tennis at one of the two courts located on site.</p>
    <p>Snorkeling and beach swimming is across the street adjacent to the Sheraton Hotel. Enjoy an evening walk to restaurants and shops at the nearby Poipu Village or Kukui'ula Shopping Center which features 'Roys' restaurant. Located on the sunny south
      shore of Poipu near world famous beaches, the Garden Isle of Kauai will not disappoint.</p>
    <p>We want your Hawaii experience to be something you can not wait to repeat. We own and manage our own property and can give you the individual attention that makes the difference.</p>
    <p>Poipu Kapili is a complete 'NO SMOKING' property. There is no smoking allowed inside our unit or anywhere on the common area.</p>
    <p>*We NEVER will ask you for a WIRE* If anyone ever asks you to wire money - you may be a victim of a scam!!! Always call us if you want any information. We are not overseas - we are in California</p>
    <p>If our calendar shows booked, please check out our other equally wonderful homes at <a href="https://www.vrbo.com/127284" target="_blank">vrbo.com/127284</a>.</p>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `ul li { display: inline; }` to your CSS

```css
html,
head {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Goudy Old Style', Garamond, 'Big Caslon', Sans-Serif;
}

ul li { display: inline; }

.header {
  background: url(https://imagesus-ssl.homeaway.com/mda01/2358e4a3-3618-473b-b198-457b887edb98.1.10) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 30em;
}
.nav {
  background: rgba(24, 24, 24, .6);
  height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: initial;
  list-style-image: initial;
  padding: 0.75em 1em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #333333;
  height: 1.5em;
}
.title {
  font-family: 'calibri', cursive;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 3em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-right: 8em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}
.supporting {
  background: #FFF9E9;
  height: 30em;
  padding: 3em;
  color: #56482D;
}
.quote {
  height: 5em 2em;
  width: 8em;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  float: left;
  font-family: cursive;
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 2em;
}
.description {
  display: block;
  float: auto;
}
.description p:nth-child(9) {
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 10x;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="btn" href="https://www.poipukapili22.com"> Home</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Reviews</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="https://www.google.com"> Photos & Videos</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Maps/Location</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Amenities</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Information</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Rates</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Check Availability</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Book Your Stay</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Contact Us</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    Poipu Kapili #22
  </div>
</div>
<div class="supporting">
  <div class="quote">
    <p>"From the lanai we watched snorkel boats and whale spouts right out front."
    </p>
    <p>Georgina Marion <span> Guest, Jan 2016</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <h1> Spectacular views and deluxe furnishings will make Poipu Kapili #22 your home away from home.</h1> 
    <p>This spacious and comfortable home has an air conditioned master suite and two full bathrooms.</p>
    <p>Enjoy the ocean views from living room, dining room, kitchen and lanai. Drift to sleep in the luxury of a king bed.</p>
    <p>The views will provide you with endless hours of seasonal whale watching and ocean views. Poipu Kapili is one of the finest resorts on Kauai. With only 60 units on five beautifully-landscaped acres Poipu Kapili offers maximum privacy. Relax and enjoy
      the view from the pool and BBQ area as well. Keep in shape and play tennis at one of the two courts located on site.</p>
    <p>Snorkeling and beach swimming is across the street adjacent to the Sheraton Hotel. Enjoy an evening walk to restaurants and shops at the nearby Poipu Village or Kukui'ula Shopping Center which features 'Roys' restaurant. Located on the sunny south
      shore of Poipu near world famous beaches, the Garden Isle of Kauai will not disappoint.</p>
    <p>We want your Hawaii experience to be something you can not wait to repeat. We own and manage our own property and can give you the individual attention that makes the difference.</p>
    <p>Poipu Kapili is a complete 'NO SMOKING' property. There is no smoking allowed inside our unit or anywhere on the common area.</p>
    <p>*We NEVER will ask you for a WIRE* If anyone ever asks you to wire money - you may be a victim of a scam!!! Always call us if you want any information. We are not overseas - we are in California</p>
    <p>If our calendar shows booked, please check out our other equally wonderful homes at <a href="https://www.vrbo.com/127284" target="_blank">vrbo.com/127284</a>.</p>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! 

What is the difference between how CSS evaluates the class "btn" and "ul li"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but there is no difference other than how you style the individual elements

Comment: I don't understand why 
    
   .nav ul li{
   display: inline-block;
   }

makes the list horizontal without bullet points when

    .btn {
    display: inline-block;
    }

does not.

Answer (score 2):

Change the list items (`<li>`) so that they're either `display:inline-block` or `float:left;`

```css
html,
head {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Goudy Old Style', Garamond, 'Big Caslon', Sans-Serif;
}
.header {
  background: url(https://imagesus-ssl.homeaway.com/mda01/2358e4a3-3618-473b-b198-457b887edb98.1.10) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 30em;
}
.nav {
  background: rgba(24, 24, 24, .6);
  height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: initial;
  list-style-image: initial;
  padding: 0.75em 1em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #333333;
  height: 1.5em;
}
.title {
  font-family: 'calibri', cursive;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 3em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-right: 8em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}
.supporting {
  background: #FFF9E9;
  height: 30em;
  padding: 3em;
  color: #56482D;
}
.quote {
  height: 5em 2em;
  width: 8em;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  float: left;
  font-family: cursive;
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 2em;
}
.description {
  display: block;
  float: auto;
}
.description p:nth-child(9) {
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 10x;
}
li {
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="btn" href="https://www.poipukapili22.com"> Home</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Reviews</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="https://www.google.com"> Photos & Videos</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Maps/Location</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Amenities</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Information</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Rates</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Check Availability</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Book Your Stay</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" href="#"> Contact Us</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    Poipu Kapili #22
  </div>
</div>
<div class="supporting">
  <div class="quote">
    <p>"From the lanai we watched snorkel boats and whale spouts right out front."
    </p>
    <p>Georgina Marion <span> Guest, Jan 2016</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <h1> Spectacular views and deluxe furnishings will make Poipu Kapili #22 your home away from home.</h1> 
    <p>This spacious and comfortable home has an air conditioned master suite and two full bathrooms.</p>
    <p>Enjoy the ocean views from living room, dining room, kitchen and lanai. Drift to sleep in the luxury of a king bed.</p>
    <p>The views will provide you with endless hours of seasonal whale watching and ocean views. Poipu Kapili is one of the finest resorts on Kauai. With only 60 units on five beautifully-landscaped acres Poipu Kapili offers maximum privacy. Relax and enjoy
      the view from the pool and BBQ area as well. Keep in shape and play tennis at one of the two courts located on site.</p>
    <p>Snorkeling and beach swimming is across the street adjacent to the Sheraton Hotel. Enjoy an evening walk to restaurants and shops at the nearby Poipu Village or Kukui'ula Shopping Center which features 'Roys' restaurant. Located on the sunny south
      shore of Poipu near world famous beaches, the Garden Isle of Kauai will not disappoint.</p>
    <p>We want your Hawaii experience to be something you can not wait to repeat. We own and manage our own property and can give you the individual attention that makes the difference.</p>
    <p>Poipu Kapili is a complete 'NO SMOKING' property. There is no smoking allowed inside our unit or anywhere on the common area.</p>
    <p>*We NEVER will ask you for a WIRE* If anyone ever asks you to wire money - you may be a victim of a scam!!! Always call us if you want any information. We are not overseas - we are in California</p>
    <p>If our calendar shows booked, please check out our other equally wonderful homes at <a href="https://www.vrbo.com/127284" target="_blank">vrbo.com/127284</a>.</p>

  </div>
```

By default list items have a display of list-item which generates a block box.

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you add this to your code

```
.nav ul li{ display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this

```css
li {
 display: inline-block;
}
```